# VBA List all possible combination of variable number of items (number of nested loops as variable)

Tags: vba, for-loop, permutation

gentleman! I am having trouble with figuring out a way to define the number of elements as variable when listing all possible combinations. I have a hard coded example of this where number of elements = 3

```
'Declare variables
Dim a as long
Dim b as Long
Dim C as Long
Dim ElementsArray  as variant

'Array
ElementsArray = array("1400","1900","2400")

'Loop through combinations
for a = lbound(ElementsArray) to ubound(ElementsArray)
    for B= lbound(ElementsArray) to ubound(ElementsArray)
        for c = lbound(ElementsArray) to ubound(ElementsArray)
        debug.print(ElementsArray(a) & " - " & ElementsArray(b) & " - " & ElementsArray(c))
        next c
    next b
next a
```

But What I am looking for is a code in which perhaps the number of nested For loops is a variable or some other ways to permutate through all possible combinations. Please help solve this problem.

Comment: nested loops can't be variable - except if you write a routine that writes the code for you, inject it into the VBE-project and execute it. However, instead of having nested loops, a recursive routine could do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I mean maybe it can be expressed as a "goto RepeatLoop" thing where the code would go through the same one for loop a necessary number of times. I guess it's kind of like your suggestion? Would you like to give an example for my code written as you suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of a recursive implementation. Just be warned that you shouldn't make your array too large as you will get n to the power of n solutions - for 4 elements, that's 256, for 5 elements 3'125, for 6 you get 46'656 and for 7 already 823'543 - don't complain if the program takes a long time to execute. And of course you need a way to *do* something with every permutation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ElementsArray  As Variant
    ElementsArray = Array("1400", "1900", "2400")
    ReDim SolutionArray(LBound(ElementsArray) To UBound(ElementsArray))
    
    recursion ElementsArray, SolutionArray, LBound(ElementsArray)
End Sub

Sub recursion(elements, solution, level As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(elements) To UBound(elements)
        solution(level) = elements(i)
        If level = UBound(elements) Then
            Debug.Print Join(solution, " - ")
        Else
            recursion elements, solution, level + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Update: This is the result:

[image]

---

**Update**
Still not sure if I understand. The following code will create a list of n-Tupel out of an array of values.
In the example (test), we have an array of 4 values and set n to 3 (defined as constant).

```
Sub test()
    Const n = 3
    Dim ElementsArray  As Variant
    ElementsArray = Array("1400", "1900", "2400", "9999")
    
    ReDim SolutionArray(0 To n - 1)
    recursion ElementsArray, SolutionArray, LBound(ElementsArray)
End Sub

Sub recursion(elements, solution, level As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(elements) To UBound(elements)
        solution(level) = elements(i)
        If level = UBound(solution) Then
            Debug.Print Join(solution, " - ")
        Else
            recursion elements, solution, level + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answer however your code returns just 3 combinations of 3 elements where only the last one is iterated

Comment: @Eduards What do you mean? The answer code returns **exactly what yours does** for the array you used/show. Is it anything I am missing? Does **your code** return what you need?

Comment: the code in the answer returns this 

"1400 - 1400- 1400"
"1400 - 1400- 1900"
"1400 - 1400- 2400"

and that's it where Mine returns every combination possible i.e. from 

"1400 - 1400- 1400" to "2400 - 2400 - 2400"

Comment: I don't understand your problem. See screenshot.

Comment: When I ran it - it returned only the first 3 combinations and exited the function. And Also I couldn't understand where do you set 3 as the number of elements

Comment: I use `UBound` and `LBound`. No need to have this hardcoded

Comment: Which ones? Why would one even need to use Ubound and Lbound here when the OP asks for that value as a single variable i.e. "3" as the example. And the idea is that this variable (number of elements in the result array) is changeable via, say, a calculation performed previously in the code

Comment: Your example array has 3 elements, which are indexed from 0 to 2. First iteration starts with Level=0 (LBound), and then the routine is called recursively until Level = 2 (UBound). At that moment, the result is dumped. But the code would also work if array would be indexed 1..3 (or -1..1 or 10..12 or any other start index). I don't see any point where I should use the value 3 explicitely

Comment: @Eduards Did you test your own code, no offence? I tested it and it returns **exactly** what the above code does! If you have something else in (your) mind, please let us know what is it about. The answer author is not a mind reader... You are talking about "1400 - 1400- 1400" to "2400 - 2400 - 2400". Where from did you bring these cases? Please, copy them from the `Immediate Window`. In this way you (probably) will understand what we try saying...

Comment: The number of elements correspond to the number of nested for loops and the OP is about having that number of levels / nested loops as variable

Comment: You mean you have an array of 5 elements and want all possible combinations of 3 elements?

Comment: @Eduards Firstly, you did not answer my above question, so I assume that you understand that the above code returns exactly what yours does. Secondly, not understanding how the code works is not a reason to consider the above code not covering **the required variable** issue... The called `Sub` iterates between all array elements and recursively calls itself **for each level**. Not needing more variables **is a gain**... Do you want **all possible combinations**, as the above code returns, or **combinations of 3**, which I have a doubt?

Comment: I need all of the combinations but I don't understand where in the code it sets the number of elements / levels to 3

Comment: @Eduards Number of elements is `UBound(elements)`. Now, what do you wand doing with the returned (all) combinations? The above solution can be adapted to return an array containing all those combinations....

Comment: The intended use is to get an array of each combination after which it would be checked if it's a valid combination, if it's not a valid combination - generate next combination and check it. What I am trying to clarify is where exactly in the code does it make the result array contain 3 elements, because that's the thing that needs to be a variable

Comment: I don't know where from but it was understood that resulting array items count must be equal to the  number of elements in ElementsArray which absolutely not true because what is asked in the OP is the variable number of nested for loops which in the resulting array corresponds to number of items in it

Comment: So let's say the resulting array is a pin code of 5 numbers where each one may be one of the three possible options. The whole point of the problem is a code where the user can change the number of numbers i.e. 5 or 4 or 2 where each one may be still one of the three possible options "1400", "1900" or "2400"

Comment: @FunThomas thanks. I don't know how to explain the problem simpler. I have an array of 3 items which are "1400", "1900" and "240' and that's a constant. What I am trying to do is to combine those 3 in every possible combination where the number of items in result array is a variable. i.e. result array may be 1 item in which case the result array would be exactly like the ElementsArray . But it could be 2 items so then I need it to return every combination possible from those 3 items like "1400,1400", "1400,1900" and so on

Comment: From what I get that the edit is also not correct because ``LBound(ElementsArray)`` being linked to the level which is the exact thing that I need as a variable that I can change. Been trying to fix it myself with partial success. I got it to have the resultarray length to be a variable but so far it just returns blanks like " - " or " - - ". STill trying to figure it out

Comment: No, you don't need `Level` as variable. `Level` is an internal counter that checks how deep the iteration currently is. The check is `level = UBound(solution)` , assuming that `solution` is an array having `n` elements.

Comment: Oh, ok I think I figured it out thanks to your edited answer. I made it even better where it gives me all combinations possible up to n so let's say n i = 4. It now returns all combinations with n = 1 , n =2, n = 3 and n = 4 which is even better for my purposes. Thanks. Checking answer as CORRECT!